# How to test if variable is in within a certain range?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, range

I'm making an if statement in objective c and would like to know if it's possible to test if a variable is **not** in the range of value x and value y. For example, something that goes along the lines of:

```
// test if float variable (called varFloat) is not in between 10.5 and 30.5

If (10.5 <! varFloat <! 30.5) {
      doStuff();
}
```

I tried that code above and it doesn't seem to work, and I'm not even sure if the `<!` operator exits. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, a value is not in a range if it is less than the lower bound or greater than the upper bound.

`if ( var < x || var > y )`

You might find a list of [operator in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) useful.